# Restrict UIButton after number of clicks in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a simple function running inside a UIButton.

I want to restrict the number of presses of the UIButton to no more than 5 times.

I am not sure whether I have to use tap gesture to count the number of clicks, or the button action method.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use `UIControl`'s standard target-action mechanism to react on button tap and `.enabled` property to disable button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to create your own button.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

    private (set) var amountOfTouches: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            if self.amountOfTouches >= 5 {
                self.enabled = false
                self.userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        self.amountOfTouches += 1
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh nice piece of code, great!  This must be the answer to choose.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
var count: Int = 1

 @IBAction func btnSendClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
      count ++
      if count == 5
      {
          sender.userInteractionEnabled = false
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variable inside of your function.

```
var CountTaps = 0 // starts with 0 at app-start

CountTaps += 1

if CountTaps <= 5{
    your code
}
```